# Audio MIDI Setup keeps changing sampling rate of MBP speakers

Tags: audio, midi

I have a MacBook Pro 13" with 10.12.6. When I set the sampling rate to 96,000 Hz but after a few minutes the app changes it back to 48,000. Is there a reason for this? How can I stop it from happening?

[image: Audio MIDI Devices]

Comment: I'd be tempted to ask why you think you need 96kHz in the first place? Music is usually 44.1, movies at 48.  Do you actually have source material at 96? Could you even tell the difference over a set of laptop speakers?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes. The difference is surprisingly quite significant. I didn't think it would make a difference either but it's like day and night. It's annoying I have to keep changing it every five minutes or so.

Comment: The difference ought to be barely perceptible even on several thousand pounds-worth of studio monitors. It ought to be completely impossible to tell over laptop speakers, as the affected frequencies are well outside their reproduction range, as well as human hearing range. You didn't specify if you have source material at 96k [or additionally if it was actually recorded at 96 or later upsampled]

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't why it might be different. I'm notice the difference on Equator and Melodics. The difference is definitely there.

Comment: I'd check with those software manufacturers for compatibility issues in that case. You really shouldn't be able to hear the difference. Nobody works at 96, file sizes are massive & really no-one can hear the difference. CDs are 44.1, movies at 48.